# Execute function when clicking on DOM element in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to execute a function when I'm clicking on elements in the dom with a specific class. It just doesn't work, but I'm also receiving any error. This is my

code snippet:

```
        methods: {
            initTab: function(){
                document.querySelectorAll('.element').onclick = this.nextTab()
            }
        },            
        mounted: function () {
            this.initTab()
        }
```

I
I want to execute the function every time I click on the element. Would be very thankful if anybody could help me :)

Comment: are you working with single file components? i have a solution to your specific need and i want to know how you are implementing vue

Comment: Hello, I‘m just using vue as a script without components. I just have a few instances :) But I‘m thinking about switching to single file components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `@click="initTab($event)"` to the document or template root, that allows you to track every `click` event on your template, that way you could put your logic to the elements which have only `.element` class name. If you're using it in a component you could do : `<template> <div @click="initTab($event)"> ... </div> </template>`

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            
        }
    },
    methods: {
    nextTab(){
    console.log("You clicked on an element with class name =element")
    },
    initTab(event){
     let targetClassNames=event.target.className.split(" ");
     targetClassNames.filter(e=>{
       if(e==="element"){

          this.nextTab();
        }
      });
    }
    },
    mounted() {
        
    }


})
```

```css
#app{
height:100px;
display:grid
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" @click="initTab($event)">
  <button class="element">1</button>
 <button class="element btn">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
   <button class="element btn-primary">4</button>
    <button class="btn elementory">5</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

There's very little need (if at all) for `document.querySelectorAll()` in a Vue app.

In this situation you can take advantage of delegation:

```vue
<div @click="onClick">
  <!-- Clicks on any element inside this div will be handled -->
</div>
```

```es6
methods: {
  onClick(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('element')) {
      // Handle the click
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use general javascript logic within vue. This is not often a good idea.

What I do in such cases is something like this:

```
<component-name @click="nextTab(tabName)"></component-name>
```

However, in a v-for loop you can also do something like this:

```
<ul v-for="tab in tabs">
  <li @click="nextTab(tab)">{{tab}}</li>
</ul>
```

That way in methods you only need:

```
methods: {
    nextTab: function(tab){
       // whatever it is you want to do here
    } 
},
```

And you won't need mounted at all.

**Conclusion**: try to avoid repetition by creating components or elements (like li) that repeat - not by trying to add an event-listener to a class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I wanted to automate every class, because I've got many elements of that on my page and won't to add the @click event every time manually.

Comment: Now you have to add that class many times. Is that really less work?